# Laravel returns 404 status on all controllers except the root page /

Tags: laravel

Сlean laravel and for some reason only returns 200 status on the root page. On other routes, I get a 404 status, and not a specially designed page for a 404 error, but a regular one in which the response sent by the controller is displayed. I can't understand what the problem is, what options could there be?

in `routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
    return response('Hello World', 200)
                  ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
});


Route::get('/duck', function () {
    return [1, 2, 3];
});
```

Comment: I think setting `APP_DEBUG` to `false` to get "_a specially designed page for a 404 error_" should work. Setting it to `true` will show error details for ... debugging. `true` should be set in DEV environments, `false` in production.

Comment: @brombeer The 404 page works correctly on all routes that do not exist, but on the routes that I added to `routes/web.php` the 404 response comes and the data is displayed in the browser.

Comment: Ah ok, wasn't clear. How do you serve your project, `php artisan serve`? If not, maybe some webserver misconfiguration?

Comment: @brombeer the site is deployed on a  vpn server and I took the configuration for nginx from my other work sites, but I'll check it again, probably still a server configuration problem, thanks!

Comment: The problem is in your Nginx/ apache configuration file. Share your web server's config file

Comment: @TipuSultanEiko thanks!  This is really the problem in my nginx conf file, I wrote the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the `nginx` configuration the part was missing. If this code is not there, then all routes except the root will be 404. There will also be a problem with route caching, you will need to clear the cache very often after editing `routes/web.php`

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would check if all routes are registered. you do that with
`php artisan route:list`. If not, then enter `php artisan route:clear`.

If that not helps you can try:
`php artisan config:cache`

Comment: all routes are in `php artisan route:list`. Never before have there been such problems.  i use `php artisan optimize:clear`  but for some reason it's still 404 response on all routes except /